# How to create a JAX-WS Webservice Client which has a dynamic header

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy, jax-ws

I have to create a client for a JAX-WS Webservice which is expecting the header to be populated .

The Body element I am able to populate correctly but I am not sure if I am able to populate the header correctly.

I am not able to find a method where I can populate the header correctly in the loaded Proxy from the webservice.

The header has a Security header and has 3 elements genid,Proj_name,username.

The body has a PN_SET_PO method which has 3 elements data,integration_id,Proj_name.

I am able to set the body correctly but my question is how to set the headers. If i look at the proxy loaded classes there I do see a security header class which can be used to set the security header but how do I pass this to the request.

In the proxy there is a Object Factory class which also has the methods but not sure how to use them .

I know one way to handle this is using the handler classes of soap.

My question is the loaded classes from proxy do have the methods to populate the header I am not sure how to use them .

I have uploaded the whole code on google drive

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mLXgRFpKi8SjNsS1hHWk5BTUk/view?usp=sharing

Regards
Ram

...................Main Class Code.......................

```
package javawebcustom.proxy.types;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javawebcustom.proxy.types.PayableProject;
import javawebcustom.proxy.types.PayableProjectSoap;
import javawebcustom.proxy.types.types.LoginResponse;
import javawebcustom.proxy.types.types.PNSETDATA;
import javawebcustom.proxy.types.types.PNSETDATAResponse;
import javawebcustom.proxy.soaphandler.HeaderHandler;
import javawebcustom.proxy.soaphandler.HeaderHandlerResolver;
import javawebcustom.proxy.valueobject.InternalVO_B5543PONE;
import javawebcustom.proxy.BusinessService;
import javawebcustom.proxy.IContext;
import javawebcustom.proxy.connection.IConnection;
import javawebcustom.proxy.util.E1MessageList;
import javawebcustom.proxy.util.SoftCodingRecordAccess;
import javawebcustom.proxy.exception.InvalidSoftCodingRecordException;
import javawebcustom.proxy.exception.ServicePropertyException;
import javawebcustom.proxy.util.ServicePropertyAccess;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SendPOOrder extends BusinessService {

public static  callPO(IContext context, IConnection connection, XML) {

    URL wsdlLocation = null;
    String username = "yesu";
    String password = "";
    String proj_name = "TEST";
    String projip = "3XY";
    String genid = "";
    String url ="";

    int Flag = 0;




         genid = FAC11;

        int integrationId = 21;



     *  ============================ */  

     // I am setting the header here 

        SecurityHeader sh = new SecurityHeader();
        sh.setProjname(proj_name);
        hh.setgenid(genid);
        hh.setUserName(username);

         PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder(wsdlLocation);
        PurchaseOrderSoap purchaseOrderSoap = PurchaseOrder.getPurchaseOrderSoap();

        Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider) payablePurchaseSoap).getRequestContext();
        reqContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);
        reqContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
        reqContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

        PNSETPO.Data data = new PNSETPO.Data();

        try 
        {
            XMLDoc = "Here will be my XML";
            if (XMLDoc != null)
            {
                data.getContent().add(XMLDoc);

     // This is the body part

                PNSETPOResponse.PNSETPOResult response = 
                        purchaseOrderSoap.pnSETPO(data, datatype, integrationId, proj_name);

                                        }

   }



}

}
```

My Question is how do I populate the header . The proxy has two methods one is Security Header which I am using above in the code and second is Object Factory both are in the proxy loaded from the webservice

... Security Header Code................

```
package javawebcustom.proxy.types;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


 /**
  * <p>Java class for SecurityHeader complex type.
  *
  * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content 
       contained 
        within this class.
  *
  * <pre>
  * &lt;complexType name="SecurityHeader">
  *   &lt;complexContent>
  *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
  *       &lt;sequence>
  *         &lt;element name="genid" type="
  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
  *         &lt;element name="proj_name" type="
  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
  *         &lt;element name="UserName" type="
  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
   *         &lt;element name="ImagePath" type="
  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
  *       &lt;/sequence>
  *       &lt;anyAttribute/>
  *     &lt;/restriction>
  *   &lt;/complexContent>
   * &lt;/complexType>
  * </pre>
   *
  *
  */
     @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
      @XmlType(name = "SecurityHeader", propOrder = { "genid", "projname", 
      "userName", "imagePath" })
        public class SecurityHeader {

@XmlElement(name = "genid")
protected String genid;
@XmlElement(name = "proj_name")
protected String projname;
@XmlElement(name = "UserName")
protected String userName;
@XmlElement(name = "ImagePath")
protected String imagePath;
@XmlAnyAttribute
private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();

/**
 * Gets the value of the genid property.
 *
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public String getgenid() {
    return genid;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the genid property.
 *
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public void setgenid(String value) {
    this.genid = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the projname property.
 *
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public String getProjName() {
    return projname;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the projname property.
 *
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public void setProjName(String value) {
    this.projname = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the userName property.
 *
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the userName property.
 *
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public void setUserName(String value) {
    this.userName = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the imagePath property.
 *
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the imagePath property.
 *
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *
 */
public void setImagePath(String value) {
    this.imagePath = value;
}

/**
 * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
 *
 * <p>
 * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and
 * the value is the string value of the attribute.
 *
 * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
 * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
 *
 *
 * @return
 *     always non-null
 */
public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
    return otherAttributes;
}

       }
```

Below is Object Factory Code

.................Object Factory Code.........................

```
  package javawebcustom.proxy.types;

   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
   import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


   /**
   * This object contains factory methods for each
    * Java content interface and Java element interface
    * generated in the javawebcustom.proxy.types package.
    * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically
      * construct new instances of the Java representation
      * for XML content. The Java representation of XML
      * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
      * and classes representing the binding of schema
      * type definitions, element declarations and model
      * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are
      * provided in this class.
      *
       */
      @XmlRegistry
      public class ObjectFactory {

private final static QName _SecurityHeader_QNAME =
    new QName("http://www.purchaseorder.com/poservices", "SecurityHeader");

/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: javawebcustom.proxy.types
 *
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNGETPOResponse }
 *
 */
public PNGETPOResponse createPNGETPOResponse() {
    return new PNGETPOResponse();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNPODATAResponse }
 *
 */
public PNPODATAResponse createPNPODATAResponse() {
    return new PNPODATAResponse();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNGETPO }
 *
 */
public PNGETPO createPNGETPO() {
    return new PNGETPO();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNPODATA }
 *
 */
public PNPODATA createPNPODATA() {
    return new PNPODATA();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link LoginResponse }
 *
 */
public LoginResponse createLoginResponse() {
    return new LoginResponse();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Login }
 *
 */
public Login createLogin() {
    return new Login();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNGETPOResponse.PNGETPOResult }
 *
 */
public PNGETPOResponse.PNGETPOResult createPNGETPOResponsePNGETPOResult() {
    return new PNGETPOResponse.PNGETPOResult();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNPODATAResponse.PNPODATAResult }
 *
 */
public PNPODATAResponse.PNPODATAResult createPNPODATAResponsePNPODATAResult() {
    return new PNPODATAResponse.PNPODATAResult();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNGETPO.Xmldata }
 *
 */
public PNGETPO.Xmldata createPNGETPOXmldata() {
    return new PNGETPO.Xmldata();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link SecurityHeader }
 *
 */
public SecurityHeader createSecurityHeader() {
    return new SecurityHeader();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link PNPODATA.Data }
 *
 */
public PNPODATA.Data createPNPODATAData() {
    return new PNPODATA.Data();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link LoginResponse.LoginResult }
 *
 */
public LoginResponse.LoginResult createLoginResponseLoginResult() {
    return new LoginResponse.LoginResult();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link SecurityHeader }{@code >}}
 *
 */
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.purchaseorder.com/poservices", name = "SecurityHeader")
public JAXBElement<SecurityHeader> createSecurityHeader(SecurityHeader value) {
    return new JAXBElement<SecurityHeader>(_SecurityHeader_QNAME, SecurityHeader.class, null, value);
}

   }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Pyves

I have uploaded the whole code in the link mentioned in the original post

Comment: I am posting it again here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mLXgRFpKi8SjNsS1hHWk5BTUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: HI

Can somebody help really need some help. Once again the question is how to use the classes in the existing proxy rather than using the soaphandler. Can somebody help